# Переход фокуса с одного поля, после ввода, на другой JS?

Tags: javascript, input, focus

html:

```
           <!DOCTYPE html>
           <html>
           <head>
           <meta charset="UTF-8">
           <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
           <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

           <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/styles.css">
  </head>
    <body>
     <form id = "mainForm">
      <div id = "div1">
       <input type="text" name="input-1" id = "input1" value="" size="10px">         
       <input type="text" name="input-2" id = "input2" value="" size="10px"> 
       <input type="text" name="input-3" id = "input3" value="" size="10px"> 
       <input type="text" name="input-4" id = "input4" value="" size="10px">

       <select id="listColor">
                         <option value="green">
                                Зеленый
                            </option>
                            <option value="red">
                                Красный
                            </option>
                            <option value="blue">
                                Синий
                            </option>
                            <option value="yellow">
                                Желтый    
                            </option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div id  = "div2">
      <input type="reset" name="Очистка формы"></td>       
      <button id = "showButton" >Отобразить данные</button>
      <button id = "insertButton">Вставка текстового поля</button>
      </div>

</form>

<script src="../js/index.controller.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Как сделать автоматическое перемещение фокуса с одного поля ввода на следующий после заполнения на JS?

Comment: а как скрипт должен понимать, что ввод закончен, по какому событию?

Comment: я это и спрашиваю

Comment: Что вы спрашиваете? Откуда скрипт может знать что вы хотите ввести, закончили вы вводить или хотите еще дописать символы? Откуда он может знать меня зовут Вадим или Вад?

Comment: Должно быть какое-то событие, по которому можно понять, что ввод завершен, например, длина введенного текста равна определенному значению или нажатие enter и т.д.

Comment: Понимаешь, для того что-бы это сделать, скрипт нужно научить понимать что ввод закончен, для этого необходимо обозначить какие-либо критерии и зависеть они должны напрямую от типа вводимой инфы. Например была введена точка, или после собачки стоит точка и 2 или 3 символа. Или же 11 чисел подряд.....

Comment: Понял, спасибо за объяснения